# DbContext shared by services (.NET core 8)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor

I have 2 different service, lets say `NavService` and `PageService`, each receives a DbContext injected in the constructor.

One service is used in NavMenu's `OnInitializedAsync`, and the other in the current page's `OnInitializedAsync`.

My problem is that I get an "A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed." exception. It seems that both services use the same instance of DbContext, leading to the exception.

My question is: how can I perform this correctly? It seems one solution is to make the DbContext transient, but on the other hand, a lot of decumentation specifies that normally this should not be required.

The DbContext is set up as usual:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

And injected as usual in the constructor:

```
public PageService(ApplicationDbContext _dbContext)
{
    dbContext = _dbContext;
}
```

*PS: This only happens with `UseSqlServer` but not with `UseSqlite`.*

Comment: How are you injecting the context? How have you set it up for injection? You need to show us code or we cannot help.

Comment: @DavidG as normal, nothing fancy. See my edit.

Comment: I would change to `AddDbContextFactory` and inject `IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>`

Answer (score 3):

Blazor Server doesn't play nice with scoped DbContexts. The scope in a Blazor Server application is the client connection, meaning the scope and thus the DbContext instance stays alive for the entire time that a person is on the site. This means that all components requested by a single user get the same instance of the DbContext and you get the errors like you described, since a DbContext instance can not process multiple database operations simultaneously.

The suggested solution is using a [DbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor). You inject this factory instead of the DbContext itself, and then you can instantiate a new DbContext whenever you need it, and dispose of it when you're done.